# Raphael js overlay multiple canvases

Tags: canvas, overlay, raphael, overlap

I have a page where i am creating two canvases and each canvas contains 1 rectangle each. I want to overlay one rectangle on another but it always goes to the end of the canvas. I know I can easily overlay one rectangle over another using single canvas but i want to do it using two canvases.

> There are two div tags *Container* & *Container1*. The *Container1* div is inside *Container* div tag. Also the ***container1*** div must remain at the center of the page.

JS Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/P9Ebd/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Canvas is basically just an SVG element inside the container element you supply, so this is a matter of positioning the `div` elements with respect to other elements in the same container. You'll probably have to use 'position: absolute' for container1.

Comment: It can be done by using 'position:absolute' but then the div doesn't remain at the center of the page.

Comment: @user1688606 true. You could, of course, work around that by wrapping it in another `div`. Something like http://jsfiddle.net/P9Ebd/15/

Comment: That is brilliant. Why didn't I think of that :D
Thanks for your help.